# How do I keep a logged-in session active from within my standalone iOS web application?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

My web app requires a log-in, which points to a single page, then populates using ajax calls. I have a timeout set for 12 hours for the active SESSION...which works great from within the browser.
Now that I've configured it for 'standalone', however, it's requiring users to sign in each time they leave the app...which is an obvious pain.

I thought I found the answer with Cache Manifest, but can't seem to get it working. Is there another approach, or something I'm missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have no expertise on it, but what about reusing the session id, save them to the database and if the user comes back, the session is restarted and the data pulled from the database?

You should use https with the session and consider to renew the session id after a while to protect the user, but this should work.

Comment: Fabian - this is what's happening as long as the user gets there from their mobile browser (they can go and come as they please, staying logged in for the pre-defined '12 hours'). As soon as they save the page to their homescreen for standalone functionality, however, every time they leave the 'app', it kills their session. I was hoping that using cache manifest to 'keep' their session active in the background (offline) would do the trick...but am having no luck. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: This was a point we discussed for a smartphone app and the advantage to have your own native app with a controllable WebView. Did you check the session-id? Is it generated all the time new? Did you try to set your own cookie wie a 3 year lifetime or something?

Comment: We haven't tried the cookie approach yet, only because my research has shown this hasn't worked (with other people) - we may have to go down this road. It's funny: we only realized this "session-death" from the standalone state yesterday...pains (and joys) of mobile development! BTW...I used to live in Wurzburg :) Thanks again Fabian.